# Open two files in emacs in "reverse" order?

Tags: emacs

Say I open two files `emacs -nw ./first-file ./second-file`. The left buffer is `second-file` and the right buffer is `first-file`. Many people are used to it and I can see the argument, but for me, it's not intuitive, as `first-file` is to the left of `second-file` in the actual command. I know I switch them afterward, but I was wondering if there was perhaps a line in .emacs that could do this automatically.

Using `GNU Emacs 25.3.2`

Comment: Would would argument be for the current behaviour in emacs? I don't get why it takes file1 and file2 and it shows them in reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

Example usage:  `/path/to/emacs -nw --eval="(my-one-two \"foo\" \"bar\")"`

```lisp
(defun my-one-two (file-one file-two)
"Display FILE-ONE to the left and FILE-TWO to the right."
(let ((buffer-one (find-file-noselect file-one))
      (buffer-two (find-file-noselect file-two)))
  (delete-other-windows)
  (set-window-buffer (selected-window) buffer-one)
  (my-display-buffer buffer-two nil 'right)))

(defun my-display-buffer (buffer-or-name alist direction &optional size pixelwise)
"BUFFER:  The buffer that will be displayed.
ALIST:  See the doc-string of `display-buffer' for more information.
DIRECTION:  Must use one of these symbols:  'left 'right 'below 'above
SIZE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
PIXELWISE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
There are three possibilities:
-  (1) If a window on the frame already displays the target buffer,
then just reuse the same window.
-  (2) If there is already a window in the specified direction in relation
to the selected window, then display the target buffer in said window.
-  (3) If there is no window in the specified direction, then create one
in that direction and display the target buffer in said window."
  (let* ((buffer
           (if (bufferp buffer-or-name)
             buffer-or-name
             (get-buffer buffer-or-name)))
         (window
           (cond
             ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
             ((window-in-direction direction))
             (t
               (split-window (selected-window) size direction pixelwise)))))
    (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)
    window))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on some kind of linux shell the easiest way I see is to use an alias:

```
alias myE="emacs -nw $2 $1"
```

To run emacs now, do: `myE file1 file2` and it executes `emacs -nw file2 file1`.

In order to persist this, put the alias command into your `~/.bashrc`.